# Nested JSON find item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following valid JSON.  It describes a tree structure:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "d1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "3"
            },
            {
                "id": "4"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "7",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "8"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "9"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "10"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "11"
            },
            {
                "id": "12"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "13"
    },
    {
        "id": "14"
    }
]
}
```

I need to be able to get any of the "items" by id and any of the child items.  For example.  Initially I tried grep:

```
var returnedData = $.grep(obj.items, function(element, index){return element.id == "2";
});
```

This worked great for item with id==2 but fails completely when I try to obtain element.id=="7"

Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a recursive function to search in the data:

```
function find(source, id)
{
    for (key in source)
    {
        var item = source[key];
        if (item.id == id)
            return item;

        // Item not returned yet. Search its children by recursive call.
        if (item.children)
        {
            var subresult = find(item.children, id);

            // If the item was found in the subchildren, return it.
            if (subresult)
                return subresult;
        }
    }
    // Nothing found yet? return null.
    return null;
}

// In the root object, the array of items is called 'items', so we pass in 
// data.items to look into. The root object itself doesn't seem to have an id anyway.
var result = find(data.items, 7);

// Show the name of item 7, if it had one... 
alert(result.name);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rj26H/

In this function I just looped over the object, so its a bit more verbose. You could probably also use $.grep to do the searching and make the code a bit smaller. Anyway, the trick is to search all children if the item is not found on the main level. Apparently `grep` doesn't work in a recursive fashion.

Comment: Thanks on the surface this looks good.  Need to test in the context of my script, but really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @GolezTrol That's really strange. Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rj26H/4/

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian Accidentally, but if item 6 would have children, then you'll see that your proposal breaks the code: http://jsfiddle.net/rj26H/6/ It's important to let the for loop continue (so don't call return) if the recursive call doesn't return an item.

Comment: (Sorry, people, I deleted an earlier comment, so this discussion looks somewhat weird, but it's about a proposed edit to the code).

Comment: @GolezTrol Yep, you are definitely right, I missed this situation. My apologies and upvote :)

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm from Python and you are my lifesaver!

Comment: @GolezTrol if an item exists at multiple position then this code only returns the 1st occurrence. How can I resolve that case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var id = 7;
var data = {"items": [{"id": "d1"},{"id": "2","children": [{"id": "3"},{"id": "7"},{"id": "11"},{"id": "12"}]}]};
function search(values) {
    $.each(values, function(i, v) {
        if (v.id == id) { 
           console.log('found', v);
           return false;
        }
        if (v.children) {
            search(v.children);
        }
    });
}
search(data.items);
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/K9GHW/1/)

Comment: It's not because it's an example that it makes `foo` or `bar` appropriate names.

Comment: @plalx function name changed

Answer (score 0):

I know this have been already answered, but I wanted to show how you could leverage the new the new [JavaScript 1.7 features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) to solve this. Please note that the same approach could have been used without support for generators, but the code would have been longer.

```
//Returns an iterator that knows how to walk a tree
function treeIterator(root, childGetter, childCountGetter) {
    let stack = [root], node;

    while (node = stack.pop()) {
        yield node;

        for (let i = childCountGetter(node); i--;) stack.push(childGetter(node, i));
    }
}

//Our custom search function
function findNodeById(tree, id) {
    let it = treeIterator(tree, 
        function (node, i) { return node.children[i]; },
        function (node) { return node.children? node.children.length : 0; }
    );

    for (let node in it) if (node.id === id) return node;

    return null;
}

var tree = {
    id: 'root',
    children: [
        { id: 'a' },
        {
            id: 'b',
            children: [
                { id: 'b1' },
                { id: 'b2' }
            ]
        },
        { id: 'c' }
    ]
};

findNodeById(tree, 'b1'); //Object { id="b1"}
```

Note that you can also set the `__iterator__` on the data structure so that functions that needs to iterate over this data structure do not have to know implementation details.

```
tree.__iterator__ = treeIterator.bind(null, tree, 
    function (node, i) { return node.children[i]; },
    function (node) { return node.children? node.children.length : 0; }
);
```

Then the `findNodeById` function can be:

```
function findNodeById(tree, id) {
    for (let node in it) if (node.id === id) return node;
    return null;
}
```